# nginx - fastcgi-mono-server 4 : upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream

Tags: asp.net, nginx, mono, devexpress, fastcgi

I am using fast-cgi-mono-server for a local asp.net web application on my macbook pro.

Configurations are:
- nginx 1.6.2
- php 5.5.14
- php-fpm 5.5.14
- mono 3.12.0

In general, all works fine, up to one page. When loading the page, the server crashes and I really struggle to understand why.

To be as precise as possible, here are the configuration files along with the different logs I think are meaningful:

1. nginx.conf:

   ```
   worker_processes  1;
   ```

   events {
               worker_connections  758;
      }

   http {
       include        mime.types;
       default_type   application/octet-stream;
       access_log     /var/www/log/nginx.access.log;
       error_log      /var/www/log/nginx.error.log;

   ```
   # Basic Settings
   sendfile on;
   tcp_nopush on;
   tcp_nodelay on;
   keepalive_timeout 65;
   types_hash_max_size 2048;


   include /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
   ```

   }
2. Unique enabled site (`/usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite`)

   `server {
           listen  80;
           server_name     my.site.com;
           access_log      /var/www/log/my.site.com.access.log;
           error_log       /var/www/log/my.site.com.error.log;

   ```
       client_header_timeout 2000;
       client_body_timeout 2000;
       send_timeout 2000;

       location / {
               root /var/www/myApp;
               index index.aspx index.html index.htm default.aspx Default.aspx;
               fastcgi_index Default.aspx;
               fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

               #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
               include /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
       }
   ```

   }
3. `my.site.com.error.log`

2015/02/09 10:10:22 [error] 1239#0: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: my.site.com, request: "GET /Views/RecipeReportViewer.aspx HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "127.0.0.1", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1/"

4. mono-error crash

   [2015-02-09 10:20:00Z] Notice  Beginning to receive records on connection.

   Feb  9 10:20:01 macbook.local mono[1301] : CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

   Feb  9 10:20:01 macbook.local mono[1301] : CGContextSynchronize: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

   Feb  9 10:20:01 macbook.local mono[1301] : CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

   Trace/BPT trap: 5

I have tried increasing buffers and timeout times for both fastcgi and nginx, but crash occurs nearly immediately on load si I doubt timeout is the issue here... I also isolated my line of code that is crashing the code (and which works perfectly fine on Debian, same configuration except I use Mono 3.10)...

If any useful, the line crashing is when calling a DevExpress library, namely the ASPXDocumentViewer. What fails is

```
this.ASPxDocumentViewer1.Report = rep;
```

I.e. when I programmatically set the report instance. Again, this works fine on Debian.

Is downgrading Mono my only option, or am I missing something obvious here that makes the library to crash ?

Thanks in advance!
Regards,
N.

EDIT: I just upgraded to Mono 3.12 on Debian and it works fine. So it's not about mono version. Any idea on where to look? Thanks!